# Adding a new library in CYGWIN (Koolplot)

Tags: c++, cygwin

I wanted to add a new graph plotting library to cygwin as i am using cygwin and netbeans to program in c++ on windows. Where can i paste the header and object files to make it work??

Comment: if this is your library, you need to compile with Cygwin or mingwin and copy to lib folder. If it is a public library such as libcurl, you can install it from the Cygwin installer

Comment: It is not a public library, i know how to copy the files to MinGW include and lib folders. But just want info about where to copy the files in CYGWIN.